# AWS Systems Manager `GetParametersByPath` API returns outdated results

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am trying to utilize SSM's [GetParametersByPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParametersByPath.html) API and I am getting outdated results which looks like a ~3 seconds caching by `Path` parameter.

**I am testing the following scenario:**

1. Get parameters by path recursively
2. Put a parameter under the tested path
3. Get parameters by path again using same arguments as in (1)

I am getting the same response in step (3) as in step (1) regardless of the changes in step (2).

I am thinking that this is related to caching because the following 2 scenarios work as expected.

**Correct behavior scenario 1:**

1. Get parameters by path recursively
2. Put a parameter under the tested path
3. Sleep for 3 seconds
4. Get parameters by path again using same parameters as in (1)

**Correct behavior scenario 2:**

1. Put a parameter under the tested path
2. Get parameters by path recursively

This behavior is consistent across different SDKs which I tried: .Net, Python (boto3) and CLI, so this is not an SKD issue.

Here is a code snippet in **Python** with **boto3** that replicates incorrect behavior:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ssm')

first = client.get_parameters_by_path(
    Path='/param-store-test/1',
    Recursive=True,
    WithDecryption=True,
    MaxResults=10)

print(first['Parameters'][0]['Version'] if first['Parameters'] else None)

put_response = client.put_parameter(
    Name='/param-store-test/1/2',
    Value='test',
    Type='SecureString',
    KeyId='alias/aws/ssm',
    Overwrite=True,
    Tier='Standard')

print("v{}".format(put_response['Version']))

second = client.get_parameters_by_path(
    Path='/param-store-test/1',
    Recursive=True,
    WithDecryption=True,
    MaxResults=10)

print(second['Parameters'][0]['Version'] if second['Parameters'] else None)
```

This code gives me the following output when run for the first time:

```
None
v1
None
```

And when run for the second time:

```
1
v2
1
```

You can see the pattern - the first request is being cached.

According to API docs: `Request results are returned on a best-effort basis.`
So is this behavior considered to be correct?
Does this mean that I don't have any way to get all parameters by path in a reliable way?

Comment: This may simply be a consequence of SSM being a distributed system with eventual consistency rather than that there is caching going on.

Comment: I tested with the following scenario: [ call GetParametersByPath for path `/a` --> Put param under path `/a/b/c` --> immediately call GetParametersByPath for path `/a/b` ] and it worked as expected, so I don't think it is related to eventual consistency.

Comment: I don't think that the system parameters are intended as a real-time messaging API in any case; something like SQS might be more appropriate, or DynamoDb.
My use of the feature is for values that have a lifetime greater than 1 hour.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the docs but AWS support has indicated in a support case that Parameter Store is eventually consistent so it should be expected that a write followed by a read may produce an outdated result

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that get_parameters_by_path() does not work as I expected.

You might think that (simplified code):

```
put_parameter('/abc/def', "123")
get_parameters_by_path('/abc/def')
```

would return "123", whereas it seems to return [] nothing.

However,

```
get_parameter('/abc/def')
```

correctly returns "123".

Also,

```
get_parameters_by_path('/abc')
```

will return '/abc/def' => "123"

So it seems to work, but not quite as one might expect.

Comment: you need to call get_parameters with Recursive=True